# Why minimal actions of a Abelian group is not proximal unless the action be tivial?

Tags: dynamical-systems, group-actions

Let $G$ be a discrete abelian group which acts minimally on a compact (for comfort, compact and metrizable) space $X$ by homeomorphisms. If the action is proximal in addition then $X$ must be a singleton. Why?

- By minimality, I mean orbit of every $x\in X$ is dense in $X$.
- By proximally, I mean for every $x, y\in X$ there is a sequence $\{g_n\}_n$ such that $\lim_n g_{n}.x=\lim_n g_{n}.y=z\in X$

Comment: Please tell us your thoughts about this problem. What have you tried?

Comment: @hans-engler This question is a generalization of a fact about the action of integers. There is no goal unless the answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. It doesn't as hard as I supposed. Indeed it is an elementary problem.

Let $g\in G$ and $x\in X$. $(x, g.x)$ is proximal so there is a net $\{h_i\}$ in $G$ such that $\lim_{i}h_i.x=\lim_{i}h_{i}.(g.x)=z\in X$. Also $G$ is abelian so $\lim_{i}h_{i}.(g.x)=\lim_{i}g.(h_{i}.x)=g.\lim_{i}h_{i}.x$. Thus we must $z=gz$ for all $g\in G$ i.e., the action has a fixed point wherease the action is minimal therefore $X$ is a singleton.